# How can I create a command alias for :Ex /path/to/directory

Tags: vimrc, command

I'm trying to make my life easier by making a shortcut for the following command

```
:Ex /path/to/directory
```

I need to to be able to press `:akeyword` and execute the command above.

The directory needs to be specified with a variable. I want to access a folder under `C:\Users\windowsusername\randomfolder`; my problem is that the username varies between my computers. So I need `$USERNAME` to be used and not some fixed name.

I guess I must add something like the following, which doesn't work.

```
:command! :akeyword :Ex "C:\Users\" . $USERNAME "\randomfolder"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User commands must start with an uppercase character, so you could do something like this:

```
:command Akeyword execute 'Ex C:\Users' . $USERNAME . '\randomfolder'
```

The key here is to use `:execute`, which executes the result of an expression as a command.

However, you can shorten this to:

```
:command Akeyword Ex $HOME\randomfolder
```

Since Vim sets the `$HOME` variable on Windows, and the Ex command appears to expand the `$HOME` variable without needing to wrap it in an `:execute` expression.